# Referir preguntas propias asociadas a otra pregunta

Tags: soporte, preguntas

El título parece un refrán pero realmente refleja exactamente la duda que tengo.

Me está sucediendo que necesito realizar una pregunta en base a un tema del cual ya tengo otras preguntas creadas que, aunque son similares, poseen un enfoque distinto. Por ejemplo, en estos momentos estoy redactando una pregunta que tiene que ver con Devops, concretamente con Docker y su funcionamiento en sistemas operativos x86.

Antes ya había realizado un pregunta en donde planteo mi duda sobre si es posible instalar Docker en sistemas operativos 32 bits. Dicha pregunta fue solucionada y parte de la respuesta fue que no existía soporte oficial de sus creadores para este tipo de sistemas. Estuve investigando y no encontré una explicación clara de por qué no existe una versión oficial de Docker 32 bits y conociendo que existen proyectos de GitHub en donde han logrado correr Docker en este tipo de plataformas me surge la pregunta que estoy formulando actualmente. Y como aún no decido el título presento 2 posibles títulos para mi pregunta nueva:

- ¿Existe alguna limitación importante que ha imposibilitado contar con una versión oficial de Docker 32 bits?
- ¿Por qué no existe oficialmente un Docker para Sistemas operativos de 32 bits (x86)?

En base a esto que menciono, ¿es posible hacer referencia de mi primera pregunta en mi segunda pregunta con el fin de describir mejor esta última? ¿Existe alguna prohibición o regla para ello?

Comment: No puedo darte una respuesta oficial pero en las colas de revisión se sugiere poner un enlace a las preguntas si sirve de contexto, así que podrías poner un link

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, justamente eso hice @KacosPro. Quedo un poco más tranquilo con tu comentario mientras espero respuesta oficial.

Comment: Y para tu duda de los sistemas operativos de 32 bits, supongo que como el [mundo va a terminar el 19 de enero del 2038](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_a%C3%B1o_2038) y docker se basa en linux creo que decidieron que es mejor no ocuparse de ese problema

Comment: @KacosPro No sabía de ese problema del año 2038 esa si es una razón técnica de peso lo suficientemente importante como para no sacar algún otro programa en 32 bits! jajaja. Si la colocas en mi pregunta la puntuo. El link es el siguiente [Por qué no existe oficialmente un Docker para Sistemas operativos de 32 bits (x86)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166921/por-qué-no-existe-oficialmente-un-docker-para-sistemas-operativos-de-32-bits-x8) y si nadie más responde la dejo como correcta, es decir, +25

Comment: @KacosPro podrías pasar por mi pregunta que dejé en el comentario anterior por favor me la están puntuando negativamente y ni me dicen cual es el problema que tiene... será que tu puedes ver si hay algo malo con ella para yo poder editarla o eliminarla si es necesario? por favor

Comment: Ni idea el porque de los votos a veces son un misterio jaja y gracias pero no siento que sea una respuesta ya que es solo una suposición :D

Comment: @KacosPro Bueno siendo una suposición igualmente es una razón técnica importante y además ni sabía de ese detalle. Muchas gracias por tu aporte y si en verdad es un misterio conocer que pasa por la mente de esos usuarios fantasma repartidores de negativos hasta voto de cierre me dieron jaja

Comment: Creo que no solo es posible, sino necesario referenciar tus otras preguntas si están relacionadas. Al preguntar lo que haces es intentar poner todo tu conocimiento, hasta dónde has llegado, para que entre todos podamos llegar a una respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaratoria @fedorqui. Me preocupaba estar rompiendo alguna regla del sitio pero ya veo que no es así. Gracias nuevamente, Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SÍ. Y no solamente sí, sino que está totalmente recomendado.

Ademas del enlace, puedes poner alguna breve (muy breve) explicación de qué se solucionó allí. Así no hay que ir y volver.

Pero como te dijeron en los comentarios: SÍ, está bien visto y es válido (y en uno de los motivos de cierre por preguntar en la casilla responder, dice que hagas referencia a esta pregunta si es necesario).

El motivo de cierre que te decia, dice asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahora te consigo una imagen.. cuando se vota por eliminar respuestas de baja calidad (o en este caso, respuestas que en realidad son preguntas), se le aclara al usuario que puede referenciar la pregunta original en su pregunta. ahora edito la respuesta con una imagen.

Comment: No está relacionado como tal pero ya que hablas justo de motivos de cierre, podrías revisar mi pregunta [Por qué no existe oficialmente un Docker para Sistemas operativos de 32 bits (x86)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166921/por-qué-no-existe-oficialmente-un-docker-para-sistemas-operativos-de-32-bits-x8) y ver si existe algún motivo de cierre? Porque no quiero que se elimine ya que me gustaría aclarar la duda que planteé allí.

Comment: Entendí después @gbianchi por eso eliminé mi primer comentario. Gracias por la aclaratoria. Justo fuí a revisar ese detalle

Comment: pasate por el [chat], pero yo no le veo nada malo

Comment: gracias @gbianchi y disculpa la molestia. Me ayudó mucho tu explicación y la de los demás usuarios que se tomaron un tiempo en aclararme esta pregunta. Un saludo y que tengas un excelente día!

Comment: gbianchi macho, ¿no tienes tildes? :)

Comment: @fedorqui su comentario fue reportado por bullying :p

Comment: @fedorqui xD! Aporte significativo! xD!